# OpenBSD netstart order

Tags: networking, network-interface, openbsd

I have two interfaces on my VPS. One is a `vio(4)` interface as egress. My `hostname.vio0` file is just

```
inet autoconf
up
```

The second one is a `wg(4)` interface. My `hostname.wg0` file contains a command at the end, `!route add ... XXX` where `...` is an IP and `XXX` is the default gateway IP of `vio0`.

But at boot, OpenBSD says

```
add host ...: gateway  XXX: Networks is unreachable
```

[The `netstart(8)` manual](https://man.openbsd.org/netstart) mentions the order interfaces are loaded, but I did not find any information about the ordering of the `vio(4)` interfaces, if it is first or last. Because after boot, I can load my interface correctly. Is there a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can determine from reading the `/etc/netstart` script, the `vio0` interface should be one of the first to be brought up (see [the first call to the `ifmstart` shell function](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/a4551fe8d769711606b758f980be5edf29edccd1/etc/netstart#L334), in which `wg0` would be explicitly ignored as it requires routing), and `wg0` seems to be configured *after* that ([the third call to `ifmstart`](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/a4551fe8d769711606b758f980be5edf29edccd1/etc/netstart#L363)).

Why `wg0` is not configured correctly for you, I don't know.  It may be a timing issue?

If you're able to manually bring the `wg0` interface up after logging in, then you *might* be able to do so from your `/etc/rc.local` script (this file does not exist by default, see [`rc(8)`](https://man.openbsd.org/rc.local)).  There, you would easily be able to add a pause before bringing your interface up by calling `sleep` with some seconds of delay.

Comment: Hi, I put routing changed to `rc.local` without any sleep and it works! I also try a !sleep at the begining of `hostname.wg0` it waits at boot but not works as described before.

Comment: Surprising:

I put a !echo "up vio0" and !echo "up wg0" in the respective hostname.if at their begining. It appears the interfaces are loaded in order, vio0 then wg0.

But I decided to put a !route -n show at the begining of hostname.wg0 (with a !sleep 10 before) and it appears only 224/4 and 127/8 in the routing table! So my vio0 interfaces is up but not configured yet... but netstart(8) manual says the default routes are loaded before wg(4).

Is it a problem with autoconf?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem and I believe the reason is that 'inet autoconf' actually doesn't wait for dhcp to be resolved. It just asks dhcpleased(8) to get the dhcp configuration and continues. Which means that the following command(s), including in other files, specifically 'router add' might run before the dhcp is actually set up, so the ip address for the route does not exist yet.